# Extra row inserted when loop through foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Im inserting cars added into shopping cart into three tables to place an order. First inserts into tbl_order.
Secondly,
If there are 2 cars and 3 addon items for each in the cart, the second table inserts two rows of cars. I used foreach loop to achieve this. Thirdly,for the addon items ,I'm inserting three times for each car in another table. I also used foreach loop.
Now, the problem is instead of two cars per order, it inserts three cars intocar table.Obviously the extra row has no car Id .
Sam for addon ,instead of six addons per order,it inserts extra one row in the addon table and the addon id is NULL.

Below is the code :

```
 <?php
//Insert order
$insert="INSERT INTO tbl_order(id,pickup_id,dropoff_id,customer_name,contact_number,remark_by_customer,pay_type,pickup_date,return_date,renting_days,amount,Create_Dt) VALUES ('$u_id','$loca_id','$drop_id','$c_name','$contact',' $c_remark','$payment_method','$date_value','$date_value_2','$r_days','$grand_sum',now())";

   mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());
         $o_id=mysql_insert_id();
         foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val)
         {
          $cars=$val['car_id'];

         $o_id=mysql_insert_id();   //retrieve order id
         //insert into tbl_orderdetail->car items      
         $order_details="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (OrderID,carName_id,Car_Unitprice,comment) VALUES ('$o_id','$cars','$grand_sum','$c_remark')";
   mysql_query($order_details)or die(mysql_error());
         }


         $o_id=mysql_insert_id();//retrieve order id
         foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key_1=>$val_1)
         {

            $adds=$val_1['addon'];
            $value_2=explode(',',$adds);
            foreach($value_2 as $v2)
            {
                echo $v2;

        //insert into tbl_orderdetail-> addon items          
        $addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) VALUES ('$o_id','$v2',0)";

        mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());
         }
         }


          ?>
```

How do I remove the extra rows ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: maybe your data may have null values..... use `if(!empty($v2))` after foreach loops....

Comment: @Torrezzzz did u mean like this?                        if(!empty($v2)){
 mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());
           }

Comment: First count($_SESSION['cart']) and then if session have any extra blank row then you have to remove that key from session. if session array did not have any blank array then you have to  check if (empty($key)){ break; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    //Insert order
    $insert="INSERT INTO tbl_order(id,pickup_id,dropoff_id,customer_name,contact_number,remark_by_customer,pay_type,p ickup_date,return_date,renting_days,amount,Create_Dt) VALUES  ('$u_id','$loca_id','$drop_id','$c_name','$contact',' $c_remark','$payment_method','$date_value','$date_value_2','$r_days','$grand_sum',now())";

    mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());
    $o_id=mysql_insert_id();
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val)
    {
    if(! empty($val['car_id']))
    {
    $cars=$val['car_id'];
    $o_id=mysql_insert_id();   //retrieve order id
    //insert into tbl_orderdetail->car items      
    $order_details="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (OrderID,carName_id,Car_Unitprice,comment) VALUES ('$o_id','$cars','$grand_sum','$c_remark')";
    mysql_query($order_details)or die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
    $o_id=mysql_insert_id();//retrieve order id
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key_1=>$val_1)
    {

    $adds=$val_1['addon'];
    $value_2=explode(',',$adds);
    foreach($value_2 as $v2)
    {
    echo $v2;
    if(! empty($v2)
    {
    //insert into tbl_orderdetail-> addon items          
    $addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price)     VALUES ('$o_id','$v2',0)";


    mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
    }


    ?>
```